# Displaying Logout button after user is logged in using Flask python

Tags: python, flask

I'd like to display a logout option only when users are logged in.

I've tried out implementing an `if statement` shown below, but all that is happening is the logout option in the navbar isn't appearing, regardless of whether or not a user is logged in.

#### Login functionality route:

```py
    @app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
    def login():
        users = mongo.db.users
        account_user = users.find_one({'name': request.form['username']})
        print (account_user)
        if account_user:
            print(request.form['password'].encode('utf-8'))
            if bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['password'].encode('utf-8'), account_user['password']) == account_user['password']:
                session['username'] = account_user['name']
                session['user_id'] = str(account_user['_id'])

                return redirect('userprofile')

        return 'Invalid username/password combination'
```

#### Jinja HTML:

```
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper grey darken-1">
          <a href="#" class="brand-logo right">B&A</a>
          <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
          {%if session['username'] == True%}
                <li><a href="{{url_for('logout')}}">Logout</a></li>
           {%else%}
               <li><a href="{{url_for('login')}}">Login</a></li>
            {% endif %}
             <li><a href="{{url_for('index_page')}}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{url_for('register')}}">Register</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Search Exercises<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to be stumped everyone is just learning after all;
i think in order to do that You can try something like this ; i will give you a short answer below but you can check this project that i did a while ago; it has an (Authentication) == Login/Logout system just like yours check this out:
(that was in Django).
[1]: https://github.com/Nouamanezh909/BLog_repo/blob/master/Posts/Templates/navigation.html

```
        short answer you can try: 

 <-- this means that user is logged in --> 
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
             # do your logic here
    
        {% else %}
             # do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

ok so I found an easier way to get it up an running, code as follows:

```
 {%if session['username']%}
            <li><a href="{{url_for('logout')}}">Logout</a></li>
       {%else%}
           <li><a href="{{url_for('login')}}">Login</a></li>
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`session['username']` is a variable that contains the username I presume? If this is the case, `session['username'] == True` will most likely never result in `True` thus the LogOut button will not be dipslayed. For example; `'tjallo' == True` will result in `False`.

You could maybe setup some kind of `userLoggedIn` variable that is a bool. @Nouamane110 Gives an example of what such check could look like. I don't know the specifics of the login-system that you are using, but I suggest looking into the documentation for the authentication, in this way you make sure you are implementing it in a proper and secure way.